# Wrong protocol when using Thin and SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, protocols, thin

So I'm running thin like this:

```
thin start --ssl
```

then I'm going to

```
https://localhost:3000/
```

There is a dummy controller action that does :

```
logger.warn root_url
```

and the output is

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Shouldn't it be `https` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Rails is this?

I can only say, than in my case I receive "https://localhost:3090/...", and I am using Rails 3.1.0.rc1 (edge - updated today).

Do you have anything special in `config/routes`?

Maybe the option `config.force_ssl` will change something in your case? (I doubt)